# Zoysia temperature range

Tags: lawn, grass, cold-weather

I'm interested in replacing my lawn with Zoysia (Empire or Empress). But I've heard it's intolerant of low temperature.

Using the [USDA Hardiness scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardiness_zone), what is the minimum it would tolerate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research, I was able to find the answer [here](http://www.yardcare.com/create/choosing-the-right-grass/warm-season-grasses/) and confirm it [here](http://www.ehow.com/facts_7901498_empire-zoysia.html). To summarise :

- Zoysia is a warm season grass
- Recommended minimum USDA Zone 6
- The best range is 7 - 9
- Zoysia will thrive up to Zone 11

I hope this can save someone else some time.